# BitmapSource.Create error - Buffer size is not large enough

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this code:

```
BitmapSource.Create(pixelWidth, pixelHeight,
                    dpiX, dpiY, image.Format, image.Palette,
                    _modifiedRgb, stride);
```

This is throwing an

> *ArgumentException - The buffer size is not enough*.

Any ideas please?

Comment: maybe a bit more code would be helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would mean that your `_modifiedRgb` isn't big enough.
It needs to contain `Height * Stride * Format.BitsPerPixel/8` bytes.

Comment: why  multiply again by  Format.BitsPerPixel/8  ? 
lets say i have a bitmap 5X5 and my Format is Gray16  
Stride = 5 * 2 ; 
bufferSize = 5 * Stride ; 

25 pixels == 50 bytes in this case. 

what your suggesting is 100 bytes for the 25 pixels.. my question is why ?